# TypeScript Parameters is throwing error when used dynamically

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to get parameters of the electron dialog but I am getting two errors:

> Type 'Dialog[U]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
>
> Type 'U' cannot be used to index type 'Dialog'.

I am doing this:

```js
declare global {
  interface Window {
    dialogOpen: <T, U = keyof Electron.Dialog>(name: U, ...options: Parameters<Electron.Dialog[U]>) => Promise<T>;
  }
}
```

I then tried to manually type the value like this and I get no error.

```js
type Test = Parameters<Electron.Dialog['showOpenDialog']>;
```

What am I doing wrong when I try to dynamically type the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is simply that the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `U` merely [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `keyof Electron.Dialog` (using the `X = Y` notation); it is not at all [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof Electron.Dialog` (using the `X extends Y` notation) .  It is not constrained at all, and therefore `Electron.Dialog[U]` might not be a valid [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).

If you fix that:

```
interface Window {
  dialogOpen: <T, U extends keyof Electron.Dialog>(
    name: U, ...options: Parameters<Electron.Dialog[U]>) => Promise<T>;
}
```

then it compiles with no error.  If you want you can keep the default also, like

```
interface Window {
  dialogOpen: <T, U extends keyof Electron.Dialog = keyof Electron.Dialog>(
    name: U, ...options: Parameters<Electron.Dialog[U]>) => Promise<T>;
}
```

depending on your use case.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7xHAvHADAWACgiBLAW0ljgFEAbYBGKFOAM2bLgHJh7HnkXANxEAJg1oBDKMDgBzWhABGk2nADeROHBLIYwKK0kJZAdV2iIAdw1btcUSVUQ5AeTDBkAIUmiAXHAAPAAqADRwAKrYcADWwACeEKw0fEwoAHQAIk6KcgB8ABTIkmTAARHh6VUQYDAkKKgBAArSJcD6UKiBdAxpyFk5LgDaEQC6eQCU2HlwTRwkqMAheSKE9g6Dbh7IAOIQEP5BYZFwoPrIoqixCUkpvQIDzvlFbeWV1bX1aM2tpR1dPX4GWyTxG4ymWBmcwgZAWS2CKzs2kcT3cni8EBgAAsAiFwlEzp5LtdEslAX1HrlonFSXcgf0QblCsVSm84FV0jU6g0flA2v9uqkHozhmNJtNZvNFstVtoAL5EBXEQgweIeODBYDoaItPl-AwAoXAzZDLioLHWNHIEVyLjjIRAA)

Comment: This works great for Classes, but errors with namespaces `fs: <T, U extends keyof typeof fs = keyof typeof fs>(
  name: U,
  ...options: Parameters<keyof typeof fs[U]>
) => Promise<T>;` in the `Parameters` utility. Any extra thoughts on that?

Comment: If you could provide a [mre] or a link to one I might have thoughts on it, but ideally you'd make a new post if you have a followup question.